# How do I create an Android project such that it does not include Android Kitkat, but works on Jelly Beans

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I had tried Android studio, android eclipse, and what not, and have constantly been getting R.java file missing error ... that never used to happen with jelly beans .

Is there a way I can use the previous version compilers, as in the ones who don't include any support library for Android kitkat?

Comment: Check if your resources have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify target API version to make it compatible for the specified API level.
cleaning project and rebuilding it will remove the R.java error

Comment: Yes Sir, I specified API version for Jelly Beans as target, and have cleaned/built project for nearly a million times Now!..fed up totally .. And this happens even for A NEW PROJECT !

Comment: Then Check your XML resources  recently edited for mistakes and syntax errors. you might have an error inside one of these files, then R class auto-generation might have aborted.

Comment: How do I know if there's any error in there?moreover,i didn't ammend my xml files at all !,,it's a brand new project with a blank activity!thanks.